# When are comments edited by moderators?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderators, specific-comment

Perhaps I missed a memo, if not a post on the subject, but upon initial searching, I cannot find a relevant answer or question specific to this query.

The query is simple, at least in my book; I wrote a comment that was meant to be vague in regards to who may have voted on a particular answer.  The comment was not rude, unwelcoming, or any of the other things that should result in a comment being edited.  It started with the words `@user Perhaps because`, and these words were edited out by a moderator.

I'd like to know how these words violate the CoC, and why what was supposed to be a vague comment was made direct.

As I'm sure most of you can attest, comments are not typically left on posts because of the backlash associated with them.  So why am I not allowed to avoid this?

In case it needs extra stating because of the lack of a question mark, the question for this question is:

How did the words `Perhaps because` violate the CoC?  The full comment is below, for transparency, before and after the edit:

**Before:**

> @user Perhaps because your answer doesn't answer the question? The code works as intended. The OP hasn't shown the community everything they need to. There is a hidden problem that none of us can see. All you have done is provide an alternative means of doing what the OP is already doing. You haven't explained what is causing the OP to experience the problem they are experiencing... not that you could, given the OP has yet to show us all relevant data.

**After:**

> Your answer doesn't answer the question? The code works as intended. The OP hasn't shown the community everything they need to. There is a hidden problem that none of us can see. All you have done is provide an alternative means of doing what the OP is already doing. You haven't explained what is causing the OP to experience the problem they are experiencing... not that you could, given the OP has yet to show us all relevant data.

Comment: Very rarely ...

Comment: My most recent mod-edits-comment was to [fix someone's broken ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ emoticon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632035/css-is-it-safe-to-use-nested-media-queries-in-2016/55292896#comment97314695_55292896) a few days ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not the moderator who did the edit, but I can tell you why it happened.

Your comment was in response to another comment on that post. That other comment drew a "no longer needed" flag, and a moderator deleted that comment. The first part of your comment only made sense as a response to the now-deleted comment, so the moderator who handled the "no longer needed" flag tried to clarify your comment.

In other words, it's not that "Perhaps because" violates the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct); it's that "@user Perhaps because" doesn't make sense when the question you are answering has been deleted.

To answer your broader question: sometimes we nuke reply comments in this scenario. But if the reply still has some value, we will edit out unneeded material and salvage what we can. This happens a lot when earlier comments get cleaned up, display names change, etc.

Comment: I can now understand why the change was made, but I still wish the change made would have left the comment vague, even if it is technically vague right now... It isn't exactly as vague as I'd like it to be, I mean.  Still, I'm not willing to delete and re-post the comment as it stands, so.. eh.

Comment: Ed's psychic abilities are well tuned. I cleaned up a bunch of "why was my answer downvoted?" comments today, because those are just so darn useless. Your comment looked like it was offering a valid criticism of the answer, so I didn't want to delete it outright. In order to maintain cohesion on the comment thread, I removed the part where you were replying to a no-longer-existing comment asking about downvotes. I should have probably changed the question mark to a period; sorry about that. Oversight on my part from doing things too quickly. @Daedalus

Comment: If you don't want to have this problem in the future, refrain from replying to "why was this downvoted?" comments, because you can expect that these will be deleted. Leave comments focused on the content of the post. If you don't personally agree with the criticisms, avoid leaving comments with your name attached that speculate as to why others might have downvoted.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the notations.  I'll make an effort to do that in the future.